# Is it possible to reference the id attribute in the create action of a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the bit.ly api and am trying to set my controller's create action up so that I can use the api only once and then store the shortened link in `@micropost.link` and reference it in my views that way.

microposts_conroller.rb

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    client = Bitly.client
    url = client.shorten("https://www.myapp.com/microposts/#{@micropost.id}")
    @micropost.link = url.short_url

    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.save
        format.html {redirect_to root_url}
        format.js
      else
        @feed_items = []
        @microposts = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
      end
    end
end
```

Is it possible to reference the id attribute of the newly created micropost within the create action?
`#{@micropost.id}` isn't working and I've tried some other things but haven't had any luck. Should I be approaching this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `.build` which only builds a model, but does not save it.

Saving the model will set the id. So you can only build the url after saving the model.

If the id is not set after saving, you will have validation errors.

So your code could look something like this:

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)

  if @micropost.save
    url = Bitly.client.shorten(micropost_url(@micropost)) 
    @micropost.update_attributes link: url.short_url

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to root_url}
      format.js
    end
  else
    @feed_items = []
    @microposts = []
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

I use `update_attributes` which will update the parameters in the database, which is cleaner then setting the link and saving a second time.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to define the `update_params` method but I was able to substitute it with `update_attributes` and it worked. `@micropost.update_attributes :link => url.short_url` thanks

Comment: You are right, that is what i intended to write :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using SQL db engine, @micropost wont have an id until you save it. Most likely you'll want save the newly created model instance twice, once to get an id and then a second time to assign the "link" attribute.

Comment: It's also quite likely that the bitly stuff would happen somewhere besides the controller, like in a delayed job with retry logic.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)

    if @micropost.save #micropost is created

    client = Bitly.client
    #using the micropost id here below
    url = client.shorten("https://www.myapp.com/microposts/#{@micropost.id}") 
    @micropost.link = url.short_url

    respond_to do |format|

    format.html {redirect_to root_url}
    format.js
    end

    else

    @feed_items = []
    @microposts = []
    render 'static_pages/home'

  end
end
```

Comment: @nathanvda Apologies for that.Can you suggest how i can improve.